# method is never used

Tags: java, android

tengo una duda por que este metodo nunca se ejecuta?no hay ningun error de sintaxis y esta bien invocado pero no logro entender porque nunca lo usa.
el metodo "public void signIn"

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity
{
Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // create a instance of SQLite Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    // Get The Refference Of Buttons
    btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
    btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

    // Set OnClick Listener on SignUp button
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  abd Start The Activity
            Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
        }
    });
}
// Methos to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
public void signIn(View V)
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.iniciar_sesion);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");

    // get the Refferences of views
    final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
    final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

    Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

    // Set On ClickListener
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get The User name and Password
            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

            // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
            String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

            // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
            if(password.equals(storedPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Solucionado, me falto definir      android:onClick="signIn"/> en el xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> method is never used

Indica que tu método no esta siendo usado, noto que tu método esta definido como:

```
  public void signIn(View V){
```

Revisa si estas llamando tu método `signIn()` desde el layout desde un elemento, si en verdad necesitas el método agrega la propiedad `android:onClick`

si lo estas llamando desde código tu método debe ser definido como :

```
public void signIn(){
```

para evitar el mensaje puedes agregar la anotación `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void signIn(View V){
...
...
```

pero es recomendable eliminar código innecesario, asegura que tu método en verdad no sea usado.

Comment: gracias @Elenasys me habia faltado poner en el .xml     android:onClick="signIn"/> para utilizar el metodo en dicho boton

Comment: Diego me parece que habias preguntado esto o es mi imaginación, bueno   como comentaba si esta definido tu método como  signIn(View V) , con el párametro (View v) se puede llamar desde el layout.

Answer (score -1):

Tenía este mismo problema, investigando descubrí que los `fragment` y las `activity` son diferentes en el Java Class.

En esta página descubrí la solución:
 [How to handle button clicks using the XML onClick within Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments)

Comment: Hola.. Debes poner una respuesta completa a la pregunta. Te recomiendo que mires [tour] y tambien [answer]. los links no son recomendados pq se pierden, es preferible que pongas el codigo de la solucion. Bienvenido!

Comment: Aunque ese enlace puede responder a la pregunta, sería ideal que especificaras cuál de las respuestas a esa pregunta de Stack Overflow en inglés es la que te sirvió (y por qué). Y también que trajeras los puntos claves de la respuesta que te sirvió a tu propia respuesta (puede que haya usuarios que no sepan inglés y a los que tu enlace no les sirva)